# SparkSQL: Use SQL inside Transform Lambda

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to access the lambda variable in the inline SQL command in a Spark SQL Transform function.

I do not want to explode and perform a join. I was hoping to perform an inline join to fetch the value for the email.

Error.

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`y.email`' given input columns: [lkp.id, lkp.display_name, lkp.email_address, lkp.uuid]
```

Code.

```
transform (
  x.license_admin,
  y -> struct (
    get_uuid(lower(trim(y.email))) as email,
    ( select coalesce(lkp.uuid, get_uuid(lower(trim(y.email))))
      from  lkp_uuid_email_map lkp
      where lkp.email_address = lower(trim(y.email))
    ) as email_02,
    generic_hash(y.first_name) as first_name
  )
) as license_admin,
```

Column Schema

```
|-- order_line_items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- additional_notes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- discounts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- discount_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- discount_percentage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- discount_reason: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- license_admin: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- license_admin_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add some sample data ??

Comment: also post complete ```transform``` code